# Using a URLConnection - getting connect timeout during read - how is that possible?

Tags: java, java-8

My code has the following:

```
HttpURLConnection urlConn = (HttpURLConnection) urls[urlIndex].openConnection();
urlConn.setDoInput (true);
urlConn.setDoOutput (true);
urlConn.setUseCaches (false);
urlConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml;charset="+charset);
urlConn.setConnectTimeout(1000); //1 second
urlConn.setReadTimeout(10000);   // 10 seconds
urlConn.connect();
```

On the last line I expect a

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
```

If the connection cannot be established to the server. This has been tested and confirmed

I continue with sending the POST request:

```
OutputStreamWriter printout = new OutputStreamWriter(urlConn.getOutputStream (), charset);
printout.write(myRequest);
printout.flush();
printout.close();
```

I then read the response

```
myRespones = UtilityClass.readFromInputStream(urlConn.getInputStream(), charset);
urlConn.getInputStream().close();
```

On the method invocation urlConn.getInputStream()  I expect a read time out if the server does not respond within 10 seconds. This has been tested and confirmed.

What we do experience in a unique case is the following stacktrace thrown from **getInputStream** method

```
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:96)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:380)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:236)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:218)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:183)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:403)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:666)
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:187)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:494)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:589)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:871)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:709)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1602)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1507)
```

How is it even possible to get a connect time out, once the connection **has** been established. I only expect a read time out. This is also confirmed by the javadoc for the method getInputStream

> Returns an input stream that reads from this open connection. A SocketTimeoutException can be thrown when reading from the returned input stream if the **read timeout** expires before data is available for read.

---

Update

Did some more testing by creating my own client and server. I did not modify the retryPost:

1. Connect successful from client->shutdown server->getInputStream()
2. Connect successful from client->getInputStream()->Shutdown server while processing request

In both cases I receive an identical stacktrace (below). It seems the connect & submit request logic is part of the native code "**waitForConnect**"

The bytesTransferred variable on the exception is 0 in both chases.

This tells me that it would be impossible in Java to distinguish between a connect error where the request is not sent and where the request is sent thus it would also be impossible to know when a failover can be done and request retried against another server.

```
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:96)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:380)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:236)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:218)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:183)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:403)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:666)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:187)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:494)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:589)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:871)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:709)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1602)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1507)
```

If I do set retryPost to false I get a different error message, but still an identical stacktrace, regardless of if the request has been sent or not.

```
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:882)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:709)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1602)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1507)
```

To me it seems this cannot be done in Java.

Comment: A quick glance on the code suggests that there is a retry feature in `HttpClient` which will try to connect again after an `IOException`. You can try running with `-Dsun.net.http.retryPost=false` to see the original `IOException`.

Comment: So what you are suggesting is that the client performs a successful connect->gets disconnected by the server->when tried to submit request  on getInputStream() it does a reconnect? And this can then be disabled using the retryPost=false, which would change the behavior to succesfull connect->gets disconnected by server->tries to submit request->another exception (but not connect timed out). Is that correctly understood?

Comment: I don’t know whether the sever disconnected. I’ve seen that the code tries to reconnect after an `IOException`, that could be a disconnect but also any other kind of I/O related problem. Since the resulting exception is the one reported by the failed reconnect, the original cause is lost. When retryPost=false, it will let the original `IOException` propagate to the caller, which will help understanding what’s going on.  After I found the property name in source code, searching for it revealed [this related bug report](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6382788)…